# Convert 〜って to 〜と思う / 〜と言う

Tags: grammar

In the book I'm reading about using **〜って** structure to replace **と** in **〜と言う** or **〜と思う**. And there's one example sentence look like this:

> 一緒に旅行に行こう**って**友達と約束したのに、仕事で行けなくなってしまいました。

If I try to convert it back to the equivalent sentence using **と** then I get the following sentence:

> 一緒に旅行に行こう**と**友達と約束したのに、仕事で行けなくなってしまいました。

But the converted sentence looks odd to me:

> 旅行に行こう**と**友達と約束した。

Could you explain to me why not using **言います** or **思います** after **と** in this case? I only know the following sentence, is used to express a plan or an intention:

> 旅行に行こう**と**思います。

Comment: The example sentence you give does not include both 「言います」and 「思います」. It makes me confused. Could you give me more information about it? And I personally think「旅行に行こうと友達と約束したのに、～」 is not so odd. I think it's a little bit formal or looks like literature.